# FInd the Single Element in a sorted array where every element occurs twice except one | Data Structures & Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I am trying to understand the solution of this problem given in this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-element-that-appears-once-in-a-sorted-array/).
It solves the problem in O(logN) time.

```
// A Binary Search based function to find the element 
// that appears only once 
void search(int *arr, int low, int high) 
{ 
     // Base cases 
    if (low > high) 
       return; 

    if (low==high) 
    { 
        printf("The required element is %d ", arr[low]); 
        return; 
    } 

    // Find the middle point 
    int mid = (low + high) / 2; 

    // If mid is even and element next to mid is 
    // same as mid, then output element lies on 
    // right side, else on left side 
    if (mid%2 == 0) 
    { 
        if (arr[mid] == arr[mid+1]) 
            search(arr, mid+2, high); 
        else
            search(arr, low, mid); 
    } 
    else  // If mid is odd 
    { 
        if (arr[mid] == arr[mid-1]) 
            search(arr, mid+1, high); 
        else
            search(arr, low, mid-1); 
    } 
}
```

I am able to understand the approach. But I am not able to understand why
when `mid` is even and `arr[mid] != arr[mid + 1]`. why are we doing `high = mid` instead of **`high = mid - 1`**. I have found the test case which takes it to the infinite loop. But, I am not able to understand a good reason why we are including `mid` again, even though we checked if above with `mid + 1`

It would be very helpful if someone can explain the clear reason why we are using `high = mid`
instead of `high = mid - 1`.

Here is the test case which takes it to infinite loop.

```
[1,1,2,3,3,4,4,8,8]
```

Comment: Please embed the code under discussion in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `mid is even and arr[mid] != arr[mid + 1]`, then the unique value can be the mid itself. So you have to run search again from `[low, mid]`. For example, consider this array

```
[1,1,2,3,3]
```

In the first pass, `mid` is even and `arr[mid] != arr[mid + 1]`. But if you only run `search` on `[low, mid-1]`, you will never find the unique number, because the number is `mid` itself.